# Does it make a difference if I specify IP or domain name with a local server?

Tags: ssh, dns, domain-name, dynamic-dns

I have a computer in my house set up at, say `<domname>.dyndns.org`, it also has a local IP of 192.168.1.101. Is it consistently faster to use `<domname>.dyndns.org` or the IP for SSH (when working inside the home network)? What about for other projects (say as a web server)?

Comment: If the difference is noticable, you need to fix your DNS config!

Comment: I didn't notice a difference, but that doesn't mean that there wasn't one!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is never faster to use a DNS name than an IP address no matter what the scenario.  If you use a DNS name, a lookup has to occur to get the IP address.  This takes time that would not be necessary if using the IP address directly.

Having said that, for all manner of reasons, it is generally best to use a DNS name whereever possible (and incur the cost of this lookup), as it means the IP address can change without reconfiguring anything else.  Of course you would need to be sure your DNS servers are robust as they become a point of failure.

Convenience is another reason, particularly if you have machines such as a laptop that might be on the internal network and the external network. If you can use DNS then your usage is the same inside and outside of the network.

Lots of domestic routers don't support accessing a public IP address that is portforwarded from the same network it is forwarded to, so take advantage of it if yours lets you.